# Firestore Cloud Function Trigger only when path updates with new entire

Tags: function, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, angularfire2, angularfire

I have a `firestore` database that looks like this

```
/entries/ ....
/users/{userid}...
```

a bunch of documents is being sent into ... of entries and `userid` contains on 8 docs of user profile information.

my problem is that the entries doc contains field hours and no relation to the user doc which contains the field `weekly_capacity`

I need to aggregate this the two fields hours/weekly capacity setting them to Full-time equivalency variable

But the Full-time equivalency needs to be accurate and this company FTE can change so it would need to calculate the FTE over various date even if the user changed their FTE status x number of times.

And the current app only fetched the entries when the user logins into the app, which can be whenever.

None of the API requests that I am using will give me a json that holds both weekly_capacity and hours on the same fetch. If every time a user logs into the app firestore calls the http to fetch all entries then how can I compare the `hours` field on the collection's entries to the `weekly_capacity` field

Just a little context: FTE = Full-time equivalency and is used to measure as a standard to see if an employee compares to there core commit hours they signed up for which is 40. SO if I agreed to work 40 and I work actually work 40 hours then I would be `1` whole FTE. If I worked 20 and I suppose to work 40 I am .5 FTE. The math is really simple it's just that in my situation the variable FTE can change any time and the app will allow the user to enter a range of dates fetching the total actual hours they worked and FTE letting them know how many hours they were supposed to work vs how many hours they actually worked. Since the variable changes, I need some way in firestore to track the change and aggregate correctly against the hours actually worked. To give an error example: let's say I changed my FTE from 1 to .7 on March 20th, I then want to generate a report of March 1 to March 30th stating my hours worked and FTE status meaning did I reach my goal. The kicker is that I can't fetch or merge the entries which hold the var `hours` and `/users/` which hold the var `weekly_capacity`.

I don't even think a cloud function would solve the problem since entries are only fetched when the user logins in right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the following for answering your question.

**Requirement**: To calculate FTE for a user when user's `weekly_capacity` is updated or user logs in.

**Problems**:

1. Some way in firestore to track the change.
2. Calculate FTE correctly according to the change.

Here's what I think will solve the problems.

1. Google Cloud Firestore supports listeners for the collections in which you store the data. So you can listen for any change in `users` collection and `entries` collection. This is how you can track the change.
2. To calculate FTE, when a change is made to `weekly_capacity` of `user` document or a new entry is made to `entries` collection you need to query both collections separately to get the records corresponding to the user affected. You can also use a [collections-group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) query for this purpose but that depends on your database design.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The calculations are still off because only when the user logs in it fetches all the entries for that user throwing them into entries. Now what about users document, it will only update when changes are made to fte. Id users hold the weekly_capacity variable and my admin makes that change then it won't actually show up until the user logs in since the harvest API we are using does not have a time stamp associated with it to that field. thus even if I add in an additional fte variable with a time stamp it still will only print when the user logs in.

Comment: Does google cloud firestore offer a cloud function to auto-login the user kind of like stich?

Comment: @NolanSingroy You have mentioned that, only when the user logs in it fetches all the entries for that user throwing them into entries. Where are the entries fetched from and thrown to entries collection in firestore? Is it via Harvest API? Also any change made to the user document by anyone can be tracked in firestore. So if admin makes the change, you can re-calculate the FTE right after the change is persisted in firestore. To recalculate you can use the existing entries for the user. Same re-calculation should be done using the new entries when the user logs in.

Comment: @NolanSingroy Yes. Google Cloud Firestore does offer a feature to get users sign in to Google and then use it to login to Firestore and access the data.

Comment: the data is fetch from harvest API. Would you mind giving an example code nodejs SDK where cloud functions can use the auth key to auto sign in a user ever 30 mins or so fetching the data and recalculate data method you talked about? Also exsiting entries will need to have a limit, what if the user changed multiple times not just once!